# Daylight basement remodel, found mold on what appears to be drywall between exterior siding and studs. Do we need to remove ALL the siding to repair?

Tags: basement, mold, siding

While working on removing paneling in the daylight basement, we discovered mold on what appears to be black papered drywall in between the exterior siding and the studs. This was pointed out during the remediation process. Do we need to remove ALL the exterior siding and this "drywall" before continuing, or can we seal it before we continue with our remodel?

Comment: Do not think it is drywall between studs and exterior sliding.  Drywall is not black or would last too long there.  Could be black fibre board.  Would try to get a small piece and see what you have.

Comment: @crip659 CertainTeed makes a gypsum wall and roof sheathing. There are two main uses: 1) one type is for high humidity areas where you’re concerned about mold, and 2) in areas where high wind is not a concern and you need a fire rating because you’re close to property lines, etc. See here: https://www.certainteed.com/drywall/sheathing/

Comment: @LeeSam  Learn something new everyday.  Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

First I’d have the mold tested. Not all mold is bad and needs to be removed.

Then I’d check with the Department of Energy (DOE) and see what they recommend for a situation like this. (I doubt if you’ll find any recommendations for this situation….too unusual.)

It’s difficult to know if ALL the sheathing needs to be removed. The DOE recommends removing or encapsulateing anything with mold on it. However, this is an unusual situation, because it would be difficult to emncapsulate the sheathing on all sides and if you remove it you’d still have to “clean” the places where it touched (studs, soffit, flashing, etc.)

If you decide to leave the sheathing and try to encapsulate it, you have to think about electrical outlet openings where the air could circulate by (and in) the openings, which could circulate the moldy air into your living space.